# Importing matplotlib.pyplot in atom editor

Tags: python, matplotlib, atom-editor

I am using pyzo to run my python scripts. However I felt the need to switch over to the Atom code editor. I can run my python scripts without any problem.

At one point I need to use the library `matplotlib`. In pyzo I would do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But it doesn't work in Atom
[image]

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\ivanl\Desktop\python trade\matplotlib.py", line 1, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>     File "C:\Users\ivanl\Desktop\python trade\matplotlib.py", line 1, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>   ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package

Where should I look for installing matplotlib? Why is it working on pyzo and not on atom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

> When a module named **spam** is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named **spam.py** in a list of directories given by the
>   variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - **PYTHONPATH** (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - the installation-dependent default.

Which means you should avoid naming your modules with the same name as standard-library or **built-in** module names.

So you should rename your script file instead of `matplotlib.py`.

Comment: Well that was quick. Thank you very much McGrady!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a error like below while trying to import Matplotlib from atom:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lanes.py", line 3, in 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'.

All I did is go to my C:\Users*user_name*.atom directory in command prompt and type pip3 install matplotlib. Now it works fine.

So in command prompt you need to give something like below:

C:\Users\*user_name*\.atom>pip3 install matplotlib.

Hope it works.