# Numpy & Matplotlib suddenly cannot be imported in Atom although it works fine in the Terminal

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, atom-editor, hydrogen

I'm regularly importing `Matplotlib` `Numpy` `PySide2` in `Atom`. They unexpectedly cannot be import for an unknown reason and then appear to be again re-importable, again unexplained.

When trying to import matplotlib with the following command

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This scripts runs without problems when I run in a `Jupyter notebook` or through the `Terminal`. But When trying to run on `Hydrogen` in `Atom`, I get the following error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-3dc8365ef973>", line 6
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I get the same error with Pyside2 when trying to run the line

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
```

I get the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2.QtWidgets'; 'PySide2' is not a package
```

Here is the path of python (after having typed `which python` in the Terminal): `/anaconda3/bin/python`

I checked that the matplotlib is installed by running the command `conda list` in the Terminal and got (among all the other packages) those lines:

```
matplotlib 2.1.2 py36h6d6146d_0
matplotlib 2.2.2 <pip>
PySide2 5.9.0a1.dev1525348214
```

I tried to run the following command in the Terminal but didn't solve the problem

`sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`
`sudo pip3 install matplotlib`

I had a similar issue with numpy when trying to import `import numpy`. Although import `numpy` was not a problem an hour ago, I get now the following error message (it seems it wants to connect to a previously used script in which numpy was used, to open numpy itself):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-592c151f282b> in <module>()
      1 # from numpy import genfromtxt as gft
----> 2 import numpy

~/Downloads/numpy.py in <module>()
----> 1 from numpy import genfromtxt
      2 my_data = genfromtxt('/Users/mymac/Documents/PyQt/image_viewer/csv_file_generator/eggs.csv',
      3     delimiter=',',
      4     dtype=None,
      5     encoding=None)

ImportError: cannot import name 'genfromtxt'
```

I had the same issue when tryin to import `opencv2`: I got the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import--------------------------- 
------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8f6675581547> in <module>()
      5 from PySide2.QtCore import *
      6 from PySide2.QtGui import *
----> 7 import cv2
      8 import numpy
      9 import csv

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I visited the following site which didn't help me (or I didn't understand how to implement exactly the steps to fix the problem)

[ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot)

[Importing matplotlib.pyplot in atom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306980/importing-matplotlib-pyplot-in-atom-editor)

[matplotlib Error: No module named matplotlib even though it is installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427708/matplotlib-error-no-module-named-matplotlib-even-though-it-is-installed)

I'm running on/with 
`python 3.6.5`
`macOS 10.13.4`
`Atom 1.27.0 x64`
`Hydrogen 2.4.1`

Comment: You need to make sure that matplotlib is installed in the Anaconda environment that you are using. Have you checked that?

Comment: Thank you @IonicSolutions. I checked that the matplotlib is installed by running the command `conda list` in the Terminal and got those 2 lines: `matplotlib 2.1.2 py36h6d6146d_0` and `matplotlib 2.2.2 <pip>`. By the way, if i can run Jupyter Notebook, doesn’t that automatically mean that the package is installed in anaconda?

Comment: I cannot understand why but I could import matplotlib for a few hours in Atom but then the problem resurfaced and received again the error message when trying to import matplotlib

Comment: I am getting similar performance. A code I run a lot will run just fine in the morning say but not run in the afternoon, the first line in my code is 'import numpy as np'. The error message says 'no module numpy'.  I'll keep trying to run it and eventually it will run.

Comment: hello for your comment @jmh. If that problem to be solved, we need to get the attention of somebody who can solve the problem. I'm unfortunately not such a person otherwise I would have solve the problem. To get the attention of that person, you can 1. upvote that question and 2. write a comment on github on the issue I opened regarding that problem: https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1315